# How to add more user Roles in Spring Lemon?

Tags: spring-lemon

Spring Lemon comes with UNVERIFIED, BLOCKED and ADMIN Roles. I'm refering to the Role interface in the AbstractUser class.
What do I do in my code, to have several additionnal roles ?

I need two roles, say TEACHER, and STUDENT, and also to make the user be a student by default on signup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because roles are nothing but Strings, just defining some more String constants anywhere in your application, say in the concrete User class, should do.

You need to override methods of `LemonService` to alter its behavior. For adding a STUDENT role to a newly signed up user, just overriding the `initUser` method should do, I think. The overridden method should call its super, and additionally add a "STUDENT" role to the `roles` collection.